# Getting the parameters and values of an attribute

Tags: c#, system.reflection

Hi I am using reflection to iterate over the attributes of the properties of this model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Username is required")]
[MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Username should not have more then 50 chars")]
[MinLength(25 , ErrorMessage = "Username should have at least 25 chars")]
 public string UserName { get; set; }

 [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
 [StringLength(25)]
 public string Password { get; set; }

 public bool RememberMe { get; set; }

foreach (var propertyInfo in type)
       var attr = propertyInfo.CustomAttributes;
       foreach (var customAttributeData in attr)
       {
             var name = customAttributeData.AttributeType.Name;
       }
}
```

I managed to get as far as getting the attribute name but I am having trouble in getting the key/value pairs of the attribute constructoro arguments.

How can I have access for example to the constructor arguments of of the attributes and there values?

An example would be being able to get : from the Required attribute ErrorMessage.Name and ErrorMessage.Value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to look for one type of attributes at a time:

```
foreach (var reqAttr in (RequiredAttribute[])propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RequiredAttribute), false))
{
    // use reqAttr.ErrorMessage and so on, in here
}
```

Comment: This is not a good solution. It's *very* unmaintainable, and *very* repetitive.

Comment: @Jason Maybe that depends on what your task is. Much of the time you want to check if the `RequiredAttribute` is present or not, and if it is there, you want to check what its properties are set to. In that case I would do as above. Of course if you want to find ***all*** types of attributes, and check which properties they happen to have, you will have to use a lot more reflection. But a typical use of attributes is like above: Check for one particular attribute only, and don't care about other attributes (whose meaning is irrelevant or unknown to you).

Comment: He didn't say specifically the required attribute, and he shows a couple of properties with a mixture of attributes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `MemberInfo.Name` and `TypedValue.Value`. Here is the code:

```
foreach (var propertyInfo in typeof(YOUR CLASS).GetProperties())
{
    var attr = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributesData();

    foreach (var customAttributeData in attr)
    {
        foreach (var item in customAttributeData.NamedArguments)
        {
            var name = item.MemberInfo.Name;
            var value = item.TypedValue.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use reflection further, using `Type.GetProperties` on each attribute, and then using `PropertyInfo.GetValue` to yank out the property values that each attribute publicly exposes.